# Prototype function undefined NodeTS

Tags: node.js, typescript, prototype

I am trying to add a prototype function on Array and have declared in a .d.ts file in my Node project as below but am still getting "paginate is not a function" but VSCode is not returning any errors when I try to access this method on an array variable.

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        paginate(filters: Object): Array<T>;
    }
}

Array.prototype.paginate = function(f): Array {
    console.log("PAGINATE !!");
    return this;
}

export {};
```

I want to be able to access this "paginate" method in my whole project globally without importing it in every single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put the prototype and typing declaration on a file, then import it on your entry file (e.g `index.ts`), then you can use it anywhere.

For example the directory will look like this

```
.
└── src
    ├── index.ts
    ├── arr.ts
    └── other.ts
```

In `arr.ts`

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    paginate(filters: Object): Array<T>;
  }
}

Array.prototype.paginate = function (f) {
  console.log("PAGINATE !!");
  return this;
};

export {};
```

then in your `index.ts`

```
import "./arr";
import otherFile from "./other";

otherFile();
```

and in `other.ts`

```
export default () => {
  [].paginate(5);
};
```

---

Not really an answer to your question, but I still think that this is a worth addition. Instead of extending the prototype, you can create your custom class that extends Array then implement your own methods

```
class PaginatedArray<T> extends Array<T> {
  currentPage = 0;
  perPage: number;

  constructor(perPage: number) {
    super();
    this.perPage = perPage;
  }

  next() {
    this.currentPage++;
    return this.getCurrentPage();
  }

  previous() {
    if (this.currentPage > 0) this.currentPage--;
    return this.getCurrentPage();
  }

  gotoPage(page: number) {
      this.currentPage = page < 0 ? 0 : page;
      return this.getCurrentPage();
  }

  getCurrentPage() {
    const start = this.currentPage * this.perPage;
    return Array.from(this.slice(start, start + this.perPage));
  }
}

const arr = new PaginatedArray<number>(2);

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) arr.push(i);

console.log(arr.getCurrentPage()); // [1, 2]
console.log(arr.next()); // [3, 4]
console.log(arr.next()); // [5, 6]
console.log(arr.next()); // [7, 8]
console.log(arr.next()); // [9]
console.log(arr.gotoPage(1)); // [3, 4]
console.log(arr.previous()); // [1, 2]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Sc3mU2Hi6UgmWHBWk1XCzXSwpswmmwX8EWSm2uB3c12079bP8vXX2+XO-mw1MZnMFpOuEA)